# Curl, file_get_contents and Instagram's CDN

Tags: php, curl, instagram, file-get-contents, remote-server

After two days of research I didn't manage to find the answer/solution to my question/problem. So, here I am. Pardon me if it's already posted somewhere, I would appreciate the link. So...

I have an app that fetches instagram content/images based on hashtags. I need to copy the selected images from the instagram cdn (imageurl) to my server.

The application used to work smooth until recently... the problem lies within:

```
$img = "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11848968_1650345541876481_204433741_n.jpg"
imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
```

The error output is: failed to open stream - SSL connection timeout

If is use
"http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_7.jpg" as url, there is no problem.

I've also tried other solutions, like using curl:

```
function getSSLPage($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // tried true/false
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // tried true/false
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,1); tried 1,2,3

$retorno['arquivo'] = curl_exec($ch); 
$retorno['status'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
$retorno['error']  = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
return $retorno;
}
var_dump(getSSLPage("https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/e35/11950482_1505223163123401_2062846740_n.jpg"));
```

The same thing happens with both urls, scontent.cdinstragram returns failed to open stream and the amazon url works fine.

The other method I tried:

```
function img_create($filename, $mime_type) 
{  
  $content = file_get_contents($filename);
  $base64   = base64_encode($content); 
  return ('data:' . $mime_type . ';base64,' . $base64);
 }
?><img src="<?php print img_create('http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_7.jpg','jpeg'); ?>" alt="random logo" />
```

Same thing, works for *distillery.s3.amazonaws.com* and doesnt work for *scontent.cdninstagram.com*

I know getting an image via php must be disabled in the scontent server, but if so, how can I possible get those images?

I've tried authenticating and listing the user's image with users/userid/media_id and providing an access token so I would get the amazonaws url but still I got scontent.cdninstagram imageurls =/

THANKS A LOT!

Comment: It's more likely to be an issue on your server than on Instagram's. Something seems to be blocking the outgoing SSL connection. Do you have a server administrator you can talk to?

Comment: HI there, yes. I've got root but the machine has a network administrator I can talk to. Any hints on where/what to check this? Have you tried it there and does it works?

Comment: I don't really have an idea. Does the curl call in your second example return the same error?

Comment: Did you tried to set headers in cURL so to specify you're getting an image? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: image/jpeg');`

Comment: An observation: `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);` you mistyped `$ch`

Comment: The Curl returns "Recv failure: Connection timed out" for the scontent.cdninstagram url. And yes I've just tried with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER and it does not work.

Comment: You could tell the network admin that you're trying to make an outbound call (on port 443 I assume) and that it's timing out. What happens if you use curl from the command line as root? `curl https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11848968_1650345541876481_204433741_n.jpg`

Comment: Thank you, still doesnt work.

Comment: Well, I've simulated your examples and all of them returned expected results. It does seems like some SSL config missing/failing at your environment as suggested by @Pekka웃. Did you tried with non-encrypted HTTP? Both links seems to respond via browser to it.

Comment: I've tried the curl on the server but for my surprise it doesnt work at all, as If curl was not present. -bash: curl: command not found - but it works on my local machine though. I guess its really a server network issue

Comment: Sorry I can't give points for comments yet, but if you guys reply with an organized suggested answer I would be glad to. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Can you try `wget` on the command line and then the URL? That would help narrow down whether it's a general issue for all outbound traffic on the server, or just PHP

Comment: hi, I've tried wget on the https://scontent.cdninstragram.com with no success... I can get connected but no data is received. on the other hand, when I try the other url as in wget http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com... it works fine. i've sent a message to the admin about ssl outbound traffic on port 443 (or other). thanks for your tips! appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on my server's firewall configuration. Once the network administrator opened the outbound traffic on 443 (SSL Port) all the examples above functioned perfeclty.

Thanks for the support, hope it helps people facing the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I did try the code below and it did work perfectly fine even on my localhost.

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11848968_1650345541876481_204433741_n.jpg');
    file_put_contents('test.jpg', $data);
```

This works very much like any other HTTP request that a browser sends to get data. So I also really think it should be either your server blocking the domain or more likely the Facebook/Instagram cdn is blocking your server IP.

I did a quick search to see if end users face similar issues on their front. Came across [this thread](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10202614254464395) on Facebook.

As one of the people suggested there, changing from "scontent" to "scontent-a" or "scontent-b" could allow people to view the images properly again. So as a quick hack and a temporary solution, I think you could just replace the sub domains and try your luck.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the tip, I've tried that with no success. still waiting on the answer from the network admin regarding outbound ssl on 443.

Answer (score 0):

In instagram developer site edit your client and enable
Non square media check box. I am able to download images to my local using file_get_contents.
Please review following code:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents ( 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $id . '/media/recent/?access_token=' . $token );
$ins_media = json_decode ( $content, true );
$i = 0;
set_time_limit ( 0 );

foreach ( $ins_media ['data'] as $vm ) :

    if ($count == $i) {
        break;
    }
    $i ++;
    $img = $vm ['images'] ['low_resolution'] ['url'];
    $link = $vm ["link"];

    $path_parts = pathinfo ( $img ); 
    $imagData= explode("?",$path_parts ['basename']);
   $content = file_get_contents($img);

   file_put_contents("/xampp/htdocs/test/uploads/$imagData[0]",$content);

    ?>
```